# Writing to a temporary file with M4

Tags: m4

M4 has a command `maketemp` which generates a random temporary file. However, what I can't figure out is how you're supposed to write to this file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope it's what you want.

```
define(_FILE,maketemp(`/tmp/m4.XXXXXX'))                                  
Created file is _FILE                                
esyscmd(`echo foo > ' _FILE)
```